# Constructing a degree-1 Lagrange interpolation polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

> Construct the Lagrange polynomial $p_1$ of degree $1$ for a continuous
>   function $f$ on $[-1, 1]$ using the points $x_0 = -1$ and $x_1 = 1$.

---

My attempt (note: I am using the notation that is used on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Here, we have $k = 1$. So,

$$\ell_{0}(x) = \prod_{0 \leq m \leq 1 \\ m \neq 0} \frac{x -  x_{m}}{x_{0} - x_{m}} = \frac{x - x_{1}}{x_{0} - x_{1}} = \frac{x - 1}{-2} = -\frac{x - 1}{2}.$$

and

$$\ell_{1}(x) = \prod_{0 \leq m \leq 1 \\ m\neq 1} \frac{x - x_{m}}{x_{1} - x_{m}} = \frac{x - x_{0}}{x_{1} - x_{0}} = \frac{x + 1}{2}.$$

Hence, our interpolation polynomial is

$$L(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{1} y_{j} \ell_{j}(x) = - y_{0} \cdot \frac{x - 1}{2} + y_{1} \cdot \frac{x + 1}{2}.$$

---

This is my first time doing this. I wanted to have someone check if I have done this correctly?

Comment: Yes, everything is alright.

Comment: Except there should not be a $x_j$ in your product. There is no $j$ anywhere: in the first it's $x_0$ (and indeed the product is over $m$ such that $m\ne0$). Likewise for the second product, where it's $x_1$ instead of $x_j$. Apart from that, you have it right.